# Import package from same project in go

Tags: go

I have a question regarding the package structure in Go. I have a project structured like this in my src directory:

```
- project
    - proto_messages
    - client
        - clientcode.go
    - server
        - servercode.go
```

In my client and server code I use imports like this: "../proto_messages" and it builds on my jenkins without any problems. The problem is, that I can't develop like this - VS Code/Go delivers the following error:

```
unexpected directory layout:
    import path: _/C_/Users/bob/Documents/go/src/prj_temp/proto_messages
    root: C:\Users\bob\Documents\go\src
    dir: C:\Users\bob\Documents\go\src\prj_temp\proto_messages
    expand root: C:\Users\bob\Documents\go
    expand dir: C:\Users\bob\Documents\go\src\prj_temp\proto_messages
    separator: \
```

when I change the import statement to "prj_temp/proto_messages" it works locally, but the jenkins build failes as it can't find the proto_messages package. Any ideas?

Greetings
Bob

Comment: What's the value of your GOPATH environment variable?

Comment: @J.B It is `C:\Users\bob\Documents\go`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the import statement should be the path after src, so in this case `prj_temp/proto_messages` is correct.

On jenkins, make sure you copy the code into the correct folder: `$GOPATH/src/prj_temp` (whatever the gopath is on jenkins)

Additionally, I recommend nesting your projects into an organization level directory, to follow the convention. Even if you have no plans to push this to a github repo, I recommend you keep your project locally at `C:\Users\bob\Documents\go\src\github.com\bob\someproject` and change all your imports to `github.com/bob/someproject/proto_messages`. I think it will make things easier when you start fetching 3rd party projects.

*Disclaimer: answer is based on knowledge I acquired prior to the release of go modules. Some of the above may no longer be necessary or recommended when fully utilizing go modules.*